# Entity Framework wait for full object load before reply

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm trying to reply an http request with a serialized object from my database with EntityFramework.
To achieve that I do the following:

```
message m = dbContext.messages.FirstOrDefault(e => e.idmessage == id);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, m);
```

But the *message* model has an attribute like this:

```
public virtual fichero fichero { get; set; }
```

If I set lazy load to **false** the *fichero* property returned is null and everything works fine. If lazy load is set to **true** I get an exception like this Lazy load true exception:

[image: Exception stack trace]

I guess it may be because I try to return the serialized object before it is fully loaded from the database, but I'm noobie with this so I'm not sure.

How can I wait till it is fully loaded before I return it? Is there any kind of *subscribe* or similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wait till it is fully loaded

Lazy loading doesn't mean that navigation properties (such as your `fichero fichero`) are loaded on the background. It means that they are loaded *when the property is requested*, for example when you write code like this:

```
var message = dbContext.Messages.FirstOrDefault(some query); // one database hit
var fichero = message.Fichero; // another database hit
```

As soon as you access the `message.Fichero` getter, the dynamically generated proxy class will execute another database query to retrieve the `Fichero`.

> it may be because I try to return the serialized object

Exactly. MVC (or Web API, or whatever) will serialize the object using reflection, and in doing so, it accesses the properties' getters, issuing another database query - but the dbContext is already disposed, so unusable for any further queries.

Possible solutions:

- Explicitly load everything you want to return from your API (`.Include(m => m.Fichero`)
- Disable lazy loading, so only your "root" entity will be returned
- Map your entities to a viewmodel/DTO, which is the recommended approach anyway

The latter would look like this:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FicheroFoo { get; set; }

    // ...
}

var message = dbContext.Messages.FirstOrDefault(some query);

var model = new MessageViewModel
{
    Message = message.Message,
    FicheroFoo = message.Fichero.Foo,
    // ...
};

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
```